# iOS - Navigationcontroller stack issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Getting the tabBarController from root view navigation stack. When I fetch the selectedcontroller from tabBar controller, app getting crash.

```
TabController *TabBar = (TabController *)viewController.navigationController.presentedViewController; 
UINavigationController *selectedNCinTab = (UINavigationController *)TabBar.selectedViewController;
```

When execute the above line getting crash. With below reason.

> -[UINavigationController selectedViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf4b0be0

Comment: try (UINavigationController *)(TabBar.selectedViewController)

Comment: are you getting the object of tab bar?
try printing it in the console. Is it the same object that you created?

Comment: Yes am getting tabbar instance...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to access navigationController.topViewController instead of presentedViewController in 1st line